# How to Add Full External URL prefix in PHP

Tags: php, image, url, csv, filepath

I have written a PHP on a page displaying info from an XML feed to another website.  On the feed I have a product image that we would like to display, but I need to add the external website address as a prefix in order for this to work.

Code I have on the feed is:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('feed/myfeed.xml');

foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
$short_description = substr($item->descshort, 0, 200); ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="lhs col-md-9">
<h3><a href="register.php"><?php echo $item->name ?></a></h3>
<p class="pri">&pound;<?php echo $item->regprice ?></p>
<p id="shown">
<?php echo $short_description; ?> ... <a href="<?php echo $item->link ?>">Read more</a></p>

</div>
<div class="rhs col-md-3"> //The following is the bit that I am struggling on
<img src="<?php echo 'http://mywebsite.com/myimagefolder/mysubimagefolder/' . $item->imgsm; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->name ?>" height="150" />
</div>
</div>
```

But all this gives me is a warning message that I have just tried to access http://mywebsite.com/myimagefolder/mysubimagefolder/

So basically how could I add http://mywebsite.com/myimagefolder/mysubimagefolder/ on the beginning and the filename after it?

Its probably very simple, but not to me.  Please could anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is giving that warning message?

Comment: Are you sure `$item->imgsml` isn't empty?

Comment: The system on the external server.  it doesn't like you just referring to the folder.  But with the full path (Url and filename), it displays the image with no problems.

Comment: @jurgemaister That was a typo, the item->imgsm isn't empty in any case, even after correcting it

Comment: Is the image being replaced by one with the error message? If yes, there is not much you can do.

Comment: @RoToRa Sorry I didn't explain very well.  The images on the page are just blank (or crosses in MSIE).  Its when I View Image Info (FireFox) that I see just the external path with no filename and its when I copy and paste that in the browser that I get the error message.

Comment: What does the generated HTML source of the page with the image look like? Is the URL the img element correct?

Comment: Did you try a `var_dump($item->imgsm)`?

What software is complaining?

Did you try `<img src=" http://mywebsite.com/myimagefolder/mysubimagefolder/<?php echo $item->imgsm; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->name ?>" height="150" />`?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/mysubfolder/<?php echo $url, $item->imgsml ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->name ?>" height="150" />
```

And this seems to work throughout. And this seems to work throughout.  Thanks @schenk, your answer was spot on.

Comment: You are welcome. But still: which part of your stack was complaining?

Comment: Hi @schenk the issue was that the url to the image folder displayed a warning page.  So http://yourwebsite.com/image-folder/ was displayed with a warning but http://yourwebsite.com/image-folder/abc-image.jpg was ok.